# Is it possible to change value and data in `<datalist>` element, without JS?

Tags: javascript, html

So .. I want to show ONE in the input, when I select **1**, is it possible without Javascript?

Code:

```
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input list="browsers" class="form-control step1" name="test" id="test" />
                        <datalist id="browsers">
                            <option data-value="ONE">1</option>
                            <option data-value="TWO">2</option>
                        </datalist>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xarvenf0/)

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use JS? You're basically asking to change one value to another, not possible in just HTML. You can use inline java script if the separate java script file is the issue.

Comment: I already tried with JS so I use `.on("input...` but if user write something after `ONE` it doesn't work properly

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far? It might easier to try and use the JS that you currently have, instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: @JackU It's edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without JavaScript. But here's an example *with* JS.

```js
// Grab the options from the datalist
const options = document.querySelectorAll('datalist option');

// Create a dictionary object that maps
// the data value against the textContent
// { 1: 'ONE', 2: 'TWO' } 
const mapped = [...options].reduce((acc, c) => {
  acc[c.textContent] = c.dataset.value;
  return acc;
}, {});

// Grab the input and add a select handler
const input = document.querySelector('#test');
input.addEventListener('select', handleChange, false);

function handleChange(e) {

  // Change the input value to the value in the dictionary
  // based on the value of the selected option. `Object.key` ensures that
  // the input is one of the keys in the mapped object otherwise you'll
  // get errors
  if (Object.keys(mapped).includes(input.value)) input.value = mapped[e.target.value];
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input list="browsers" class="form-control step1" name="test" id="test" />
    <datalist id="browsers">
     <option data-value="ONE">1</option>
     <option data-value="TWO">2</option>
   </datalist>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I select 2, it shows me 2 in the input, instead of TWO ?

Comment: Works fine for me